# Improved Tag Popup

Tags: script, tags

## Improved Tag Popup

Inspired by [this feature request by Andrew Leach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314150/295232),
this script adds some extra links in the new tag popup,
to view and edit the full tag information (wiki and excerpt).

[image]

### Installation

- Install the userscript with
  [this direct link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/improved-tag-popup/improved-tag-popup.user.js).

<sub>developed & tested with Violentmonkey on Firefox</sub>